# How to link ContainerView of one Storyboard to ViewController in another Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uicontainerview

As explained in [this video at timestamp](https://youtu.be/4n6nP4njp9o?t=645) --> 2 ViewControllers  having 1 ContainerView each. And each container view is linked to a SmallViewController using a Segue.

In my case I am having multiple storyboards.
I want to link all the different ContainerView(s) of different ViewController in different Storyboard to a common SmallViewController.

Kindly guide how this situation can be achieved.

P.S. : by "SmallViewController" I mean ContainerView's ViewController.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is called "storyboard references". With storyboard references you can navigate to another storyboard's viewcontroller via pushing that vc by reference.

Comment: Yes, this keyword is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer than. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is called "storyboard references". With storyboard references you can navigate to another storyboard's viewcontroller via pushing that vc by reference.